# Компиляция JasperReport без Groovy

Tags: java, jasperreports

Не могу скомпилировать отчет (с подотчетами) без добавления в проект библиотеки *groovy_x.xx*. в IReport отчет формируется без проблем.

Пробовал убирать в *.jrxml* файле параметр `[language="groovy"]`. Также пробовал замену на `[language="java"]`, но на выходе все время получаю:

> jasper java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationFailedException

При этом

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReport(masterReportFileName).getLanguage()
```

сообщает, что язык Java.

Данные в подотчет передаю через `DataSource Expression`:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{field})
```

Comment: можете предоставить код контроллера? без `groovy` можно в контроллере сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что iReport в параметрах, по умолчанию ставил groovy и игнорировал язык указанный в самом файле отчета